# No result defined for action iland.login.LoginAction and result AddBill

Tags: struts2

I am getting following exception

```
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: No result defined for action iland.login.LoginAction and result AddBill
    No result defined for action iland.login.LoginAction and result AddBill
```

Here AddBill amd dashboard are two actions based on role value I would like to redirect it to appropriate action

In action:

```
if (role > 3) {
                return "dashboard";
            } else if (role <= 3) {
                return "AddBill";
            }
```

In struts.xml

```
<action name="login" class="iland.login.LoginAction" method="doLogin">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">${url}</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="dashboard" class="iland.login.DashBoardAction" method="fetch">
            <result name="success">/pages/dashboadr.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/dashboadr.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
 <action name="AddBill"  class="iland.login.LoginForPage">
            <result name="success">/pages/billing/AddBill.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/billing/AddBill.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Comment: The error clearly says that you don't have an `AddBill` result. Add one.

Comment: In action I have included `AddBill` and `dashboard`

Comment: Those are not results but actions.

Comment: I tried `/pages/dashboadr.jsp` also but showing same error

Comment: If we write  `<result name="success" type="redirect">AddBill</result>` this will redirected to `AddBill` action. then what may be problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always return a `RESULT`.

A `RESULT` may be mapped to another `Action` with `the RedirectAction` result type. You can't call an action by returning its name.

You need this:

```xml
<action name="login" class="iland.login.LoginAction" method="doLogin">
    <result name="success" type="redirect">${url}</result>
    <result name="input">/pages/login.jsp</result>

    <result name="AddBill" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">AddBill</param>
    </result>

</action>

<action name="AddBill"  class="iland.login.LoginForPage">
    <result name="success">/pages/billing/AddBill.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/pages/billing/AddBill.jsp</result>
    <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

---

**Edit**

Otherwise, as suggested by @LukaszLenart 's comment, you can return [an instance](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ServletActionRedirectResult.html) of the Result interface directly from the action:

```java
return new ServletActionRedirectResult("AddBill");
```

Comment: Just to correct common mistake - you can always return instance of `Result` interface directly from action. It isn't documented but it works - the next version of docs will contain note about that